# c++: Not able to understand Message Handlers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Actually I am new to writing handlers but somehow i managed to write this piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
typedef void (test::*MsgHandler)(int handle);

test()
{
    cout<<"costructor called"<<endl;
}

void Initialize()
{
    add_msg_Handler(4,&test::System);
}

void System(int handle)
{
    cout<<endl<<"Inside System()"<<endl;
    cout<<"handle:"<<handle<<endl;
}

protected:
MsgHandler message[20];
void add_msg_Handler(int idx,MsgHandler handler)
{
    cout<<endl<<"Inside add_msg_Handler()"<<endl;
    cout<<"handler:"<<handler<<endl;
    message[idx]=handler;
    cout<<"message:"<<message[idx]<<endl;
}
};

int main()
{
test obj;
obj.Initialize();

return 0;
}
```

This code is working fine, I get the output as:

```
costructor called

Inside add_msg_Handler()
handler:1
message:1
```

But there are several things beyond my scope. If I am right System() should have been called in this line:

```
add_msg_Handler(4,&test::System);
```

but this is not happening. I need help on rectifying this.

Second thing is, I am not able to understand why I am getting such output:

```
handler:1
```

I mean how does handler got initialized to 1.Can somebody help me in solving this??

Comment: how is MsgHandler defined?

Comment: "If I am right System() should have been called" — Nope, you never called System() or handler().

Comment: @ShlomiAgiv On line 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&test::System` is not a function call, it's a pointer to the member function `test::System`.
(A call would look like `System(0)` and wouldn't compile if you used it as the parameter in question.)

If you look at the definition of `add_msg_handler`:

```
cout<<endl<<"Inside add_msg_Handler()"<<endl;
cout<<"handler:"<<handler<<endl;
message[idx]=handler;
cout<<"message:"<<message[idx]<<endl;
```

there's not a single place that calls the function `handler`.
(A call would look like `(this->*handler)(0)` or `(this->*message[idx])(0)`.)

So the function isn't called because there's nothing in your code that calls it.

The output is `1` because

- `handler` is a pointer to a member function
- there's no overload of `<<` for pointers to member functions
- there *is* an implicit conversion from pointer to member function to `bool`
- there's an overload of `<<` for `bool`
- a non-null pointer is implicitly converted to `true`
- `true` outputs as `1` by default.